# How should I feed my knowledge graph in neo4j to llama2 model .?

Tags: neo4j, llama, llama-index, knowledge-graph

Stack Overflow Question Body: Extracting Nodes and Relationships from Knowledge Graph
I've built a knowledge graph and want to extract all the nodes and their relationships for further processing. I'm familiar with methods like Breadth-First Search (BFS) and Cypher queries (for Neo4j).

My Question:

What's the most efficient and comprehensive approach to extract all nodes and relationships from a knowledge graph?
Are there any specific considerations for using BFS or Cypher queries in this context?
I've also come across Llama Indexing, but it seems more suited for text documents. Is there a similar indexing approach for knowledge graphs?

Additional Information:

Knowledge Graph Type: Neo4j
Extraction Purpose: to feed to llma model to train the model for customize
Here's what I've tried so far:
i have tried llamaindex . but i didnt get a clear image
I appreciate any insights or recommendations!